# Eclipse+MINGW+wxWidgets with error cannot find -lXXX

Tags: eclipse-plugin, wxwidgets

yeah,i'm tring to use wxWidgets on Eclipse in C++.
But it failed when built. 
Eclipse:Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers(Mars)
MINGW:GCC 4.8.1
wxWidgets:3.0.2

i am sure i have setup the eclipse with MINGW properly and wxWidgets libs are fine.
But, when i build the project, errors occur.

this is how i include:
[image]

this is my code:
[image]

import lib needed:
[image]

this is error:
[image]

I don't understand why it cannot find the lib file when i give the right path and import the .a libs?

Comment: How you build the libs ? Are you using Bakefiles ?

Comment: I download the libs built already, and it works cause I made it using codeblocks.But I would like to use Eclipse.So I post my question,

Comment: are there any `makefile.gcc` in wxwidgets and subfolders ?

Comment: yeah, there is.wxWidgets-3.0.2->demos->makefile.gcc

Comment: have you test `make -f makefile.gcc` ? To build the demos makefiles.

Comment: I just failed compiled the libs, so I download the libs built already.

Comment: For the lib files such as libmyfile.a, you need to tell Eclipse as myfile.a; just strip away the 'lib' part.